# Split Laravel 5.3 app in packages

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

How do I split an app into different modules/packages?

At the moment I plan the following packages:

- Common (models, services, ... used in other packages)
- Web (Frontend for users)
- API

Comment: Split API and frontend, not sure how you split API from models/services (except using repository pattern)... too tedious.

Comment: Models and services should moved to common package and used by both.. web and api

Comment: If you know the answer why ask? Make API using Laravel or whatever you want and just consume it using some JavaScript FW (thats it).

Answer (score 1):

You can split your laravel app using a specific package called [Lpackager](https://github.com/amranidev/lpackager).

1. Easy to use.
2. Generate your package via an artisan command `php artisan lpackager:package <PackageName> <PackagePath> <"NameSpace">`
3. Ability to generate CRUD for your packages/modules using [scaffold-interface](https://github.com/amranidev/scaffold-interface).